# Justifying a Type Equivalency Asserted in Haskell Lens Library

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

According to the [tutorial on Lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html#g:2):

```
type Getting b a b  = (b -> Const b b) -> (a -> Const b a)

-- ... equivalent to: (b ->       b  ) -> (a ->       b  )

-- ... equivalent to:                     (a ->       b  )
```

**Question:** Why is `(b -> b) -> (a -> b)` equivalent to `(a -> b)`?

Comment: It isn't. It's a lie.

Comment: On the other hand, the type `(forall b. b -> b) -> (a -> b)` is much more defensibly equivalent to `(a -> b)` (up to the usual caveats about defined-ness). Perhaps that is the kind of thing the tutorial was trying to convey -- or perhaps it is the mistake the author made, and should be fixed up not to claim equivalence at all.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think my answer probably gets at what was really intended.

Comment: @dfeuer I think so, too. Perhaps this fix can be back-ported to the tutorial itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tutorial isn't very precise about this. Here's the full definition of `Getting`:

```
type Getting r s a = (a -> Const r a) -> s -> Const r s
```

Stripping off the `newtype` noise,

```
Getting r s a ~= (a -> r) -> s -> r
```

The interesting isomorphism you should get from this is the following:

```
(forall r. Getting r s a) ~= s -> a
```

In a now-deleted comment, chi pointed out that this is a special case of the [Yoneda lemma](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/bartosz/understanding-yoneda).

The isomorphism is witnessed by

```
fromGetting :: Getting a s a -> (s -> a)
fromGetting g = getConst . g Const
           -- ~= g id

-- Note that the type of fromGetting is a harmless generalization of
-- fromGetting :: (forall r. Getting r s a) -> (s -> a)

toGetting :: (s -> a) -> Getting r s a
toGetting f g = Const . getConst . g . f
           -- ~= g . f

-- Note that you can read the signature of toGetting as
-- toGetting :: (s -> a) -> (forall r. Getting r s a)
```

Neither `fromGetting` nor `toGetting` has a rank-2 type, but to *describe* the isomorphism, the `forall` is essential. Why is this an isomorphism?.

One side is easy: ignoring the `Const` noise,

```
  fromGetting (toGetting f)
= toGetting f id
= id . f
= f
```

The other side is trickier.

```
  toGetting (fromGetting f)
= toGetting (f id)
= \g -> toGetting (f id) g
= \g -> g . f id
```

Why is this equivalent to `f`? The `forall` is the key here:

```
f :: forall r. Getting r s a
  -- forall r. (a -> r) -> s -> r
```

`f` has no way to produce an `r` except by applying the passed function (let's call it `p`) to a value of type `a`. It's given nothing but `p` and a value of type `s`. So `f` really can't do anything except extract an `a` from the `s` and apply `p` to the result. That is, `f p` must "factor" into the composition of two functions:

```
f p = p . h
```

So

```
g . f id = g . (id . h) = g . h = f g
```

Answer (score 1):

The type says "You give me a `b -> b` and an `a`, and I'll give you a `b`." What can a function with that type do with its `b -> b`? Two options:

1. Ignore the function altogether
2. Apply it to a `b`

How do you get hold of a `b` to apply the function to? You use the `a` to produce one. So either way, it has to do the work of an `a -> b`.

Here's some code to witness the (*edit: not-quite*) isomorphism.

```
in :: ((b -> b) -> a -> b) -> (a -> b)
in f x = f id x

out :: (a -> b) -> ((b -> b) -> a -> b)
out f g x = g (f x)
```

Comment: It's not quite an isomorphism because a function of type `((b -> b) -> a -> b)` might apply the first argument not only once.

Comment: In `in f x`, is `f :: b -> b` and `x :: a`?

Comment: `f` is `((b -> b) -> a -> b)` and `x` is `a`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, makes me wonder, if there is no isomorphism, in what sense are the types equivalent?

Comment: Let `zero f x = x; one f x = f x; two f x = f (f x)`. Then `out (in zero) = out (in one) = out (in two) = one`, but `zero /= one` and `one /= two`, so this is not an isomorphism at all!

Comment: I think the trick is that the original function is a `Lens`, which requires the argument to be used exactly once in a certain way, so that `Getting` is an over-approximation of the actual domain to consider.